# CREATEJS: How to check if an sprite object is currently visible/rendered on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screen, createjs

CreateJS:

**Is there a method or a hidden function to show if the object/sprite is rendered on the Screen?**

I don't mean the **.visible = true** variable
or the **.isvisible()** method because "This does not account for whether it would be visible within the boundaries of the stage."

What i tried is to calculate if it can be seen by the position of the object and the screen size. But I think it's very inefficient!

Is there a better way/variable/function/workaround?

Comment: There is nothing in EaselJS to determine this. If your object has bounds (ie, is not a Shape), then you can get those bounds relative to the stage, and do a fairly simple rectangle-rectangle comparison. Is that what you are already doing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is kind of what i do right now.